# Laravel9 : update method doesn't work(controller)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I would like to ask you that update method doesn't work with my code in controller on Laravel.

I want to do is
updating information that are required

As details of code below, I want to update "Shop Information" and I tried:

1. adding $id inside brackets

now, it is "public function update(Request $request, $id)"

2. using "if" to make conditional branch that it is requested or not.

   ```
   {   
       $requestData = Shop::find($id);
       $requestData->name = $request->name;
       if(empty($request->email)){
           $request->email = NULL;
       } else {
           $requestData->email = $request->email;
       }

       if(empty($request->description)){
           $request->description = NULL;
       } else {
           $requestData->description = $request->description;
       }

       if($request->hasFile('image')){
       $fileName = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
       $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('shops', $fileName, 'public');
       $requestData['image'] = '/storage/shops'.$path;
       }

       $requestData->update();
       return redirect()->route('shops');
   }
   ```

Comment: If you're modifying properties like `$requestData->email = $request->email;`, then you need to call `$requestData->save()` at the end, not `$requestData->update()`. The `update()` method expects an array, like `$requestData->update(['description' => $request->description, 'email' => $request->email])`. You're mixing and matching approaches here, and that just doesn't work.

Comment: Also, `$request->email = NULL;` and `$request->description = NULL;` don't do anything; you can remove those lines completely.

Comment: Tim Lewis is correct. As long as you are not validating your input, then there is absolutely no need for the ```if``` statements you wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `update()` method expects an array as an argument. You should make use of the `save()` method instead. Also you should not have those `if` statements since you are not validating your input.

That being said, your code should be like this instead:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {   
  $requestData = Shop::find($id);
  $requestData->name = $request->name;
  $requestData->email = $request->email;
  $requestData->description = $request->description;
  
  if($request->hasFile('image')){
    $fileName = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('shops', $fileName, 'public');
    $requestData['image'] = '/storage/shops'.$path;
  }

  $requestData->save();
  return redirect()->route('shops');
}
```